# Text loses style during hero animation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, text, widget, transition

As you can see from the gif and from the code below I have a container and a text widget, both wrapped in a hero widget.

When the container is clicked the second page opens. I would like to have a hero animation for both widgets.

The animations of the container works great. The text however seems to lose the style while the transition is happening.

Any idea on how to fix it?

[image: Tranition]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomeScreen(),
      routes: {
        HomeScreen.routName: (context) => const HomeScreen(),
        SecondSceen.routeName: (context) => const SecondSceen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routName = '/home-screen';

  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SecondSceen.routeName),
            child: Hero(
              tag: 'box',
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                height: 210,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
            height: 210,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 8, 16),
              child: Column(
                children: const [
                  Hero(
                    tag: 'text',
                    child: Text(
                      "MY HEADER",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 28, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class SecondSceen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/note-screen';

  const SecondSceen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Hero(
          tag: 'text',
          child: Text(
            "MY HEADER",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Stack(children: [
        Hero(
          tag: 'box',
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using individual `TextStyle` objects, use some style coming from the context. This way even during the animation, the styles will be based on the `Theme` of your `MaterialApp`.

For both `Text` widgets, instead of:

```
style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
```

try:

```
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6, // or some other style
```

(You will need to remove `const` keywords because these are no longer constants.)

You can easily customize any built in style using `copyWith`, for example:

```
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6!.copyWith(
  fontSize: 28,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
```

In general it is a good practice in my opinion to use `Theme` styles.

Comment: And what if we use the Google fonts library ?

Comment: You can set the `fontFamily` to the desired font after it is properly added to your project (assets folder, pubspec.yaml).

Comment: I am using Google font and its showing red color text when moving from screen A to B

Comment: And did you set the `fontFamily` in the `Theme`?

Comment: yes this is my instance of textStyle:
  static TextStyle bodyBoldStyle = GoogleFonts.urbanist(fontSize: 14.sp, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);

and this is how I am using it:
 Text("message", style: AppTextTheme. bodyBoldStyle)

Comment: Try to define the `fontFamily` globally in the `Theme` or add custom styles definition to the `Theme` and use `Theme.of(context)...` when setting `style`. See [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes).

Comment: got it
let me try this.

Answer (score 1):

It is an known Flutter issue. Someone posted a solution here. Good for anyone who may have the same question in the future:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30647#issuecomment-480980280

```
  Widget _flightShuttleBuilder(
    BuildContext flightContext,
    Animation<double> animation,
    HeroFlightDirection flightDirection,
    BuildContext fromHeroContext,
    BuildContext toHeroContext,
  ) {
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: DefaultTextStyle.of(toHeroContext).style,
      child: toHeroContext.widget,
    );
  }
  ...

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    ...
        child: Hero(
          tag: 'text',
          flightShuttleBuilder: _flightShuttleBuilder,
          child: Text('Text'),
        ),
```